# Deleted ec2 instances will be counted in free tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created instances in AWS free tier account. Hope max 20 instances can be created under free tier. I have created some 18 instances. Again if I want to create a 5more instance it's not possible as it reaches max, so I am planning delete 3 and create another 5. So will it count that 3 deleted instance or won't be any problem?

Answer (score 2):

With AWS free tier, you can run a maximim of 750 free machine hours of micro instances. There shouldn't be a "maximum number of instances". You will just be billed for usage of micro instances that exceeds 750 hours per month, which would be equivalent to one micro instance running 24x7. You'd also be billed normally for any of the larger instance configurations.

For reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-limits.html#hourly-limits

Very similar question answered: [Amazon EC2 Free tier - how many instances can I run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042025/amazon-ec2-free-tier-how-many-instances-can-i-run)

Comment: All accounts have a maximum number of instances that can be launched, by instance type, by region. The values vary,  but 20 is a common default value for smaller machines, with larger machine limits lower, in some cases set to a maximum of 0.  Launching more requires you to explain your use case and request a limit increase from AWS Support.  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-limit/

Answer (score 0):

you have to check aws details for free teir you have to read all limits there 750 hours are free in ec2

> https://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/

you can check this out for more info
 you will be charged on your usages based.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS free tier account, you can delete and recreate another t2.micro instance without being charged for it. But make sure you are not exceeding 750 hours per month.

Comment: Hi Sriram, Thanks for your response. I have one more clarification. Does this 750 hour is for individual instance or the addition of all instances running. Say 10 instances running for 10 hours results in 10hours or 100 hours?

Comment: @Dhamodharan Yes, 750 hours is addition of all instances running. Example: If running 10 instances for 10 hours results in 100 hours.

Comment: @Sriram- thanks for your response. Got clear.